# Can I Reinstall and Format An Encrypted Hard-drive?

Tags: installation, hard-drive, encryption, format

In layman's terms, I'm essentially trying to do a reset on my computer. It's my secondary desktop, so I don't have anything important on it. But since I moved, I misplaced my passphrase for the disk encryption. Can I just reinstall Ubuntu and format the hard drive completely? Get rid of the encryption and wipe the drive?

Comment: If the disk has "software encryption" then sure, you will have no problem. But if it has a "hardware encryption" (firmware) then things getting more difficult. It would be helpful to provide more info. How Ubuntu acts when you boot from a Live USB ? recognizes the disk ?

Answer (score 1):

If you reformat an encrypted drive you will lose the data that is encrypted; so yes. Just think of it as another filesystem but with encryption.