# Lost password for LUKS encrypted Ubuntu SSD. How do I reformat it?

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, ssd, luks

The entire disk was encrypted with LUKS.

If it helps, I believe this may have been the tutorial I used: https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-22-04-enable-full-disk-encryption

There wasn't any important information on the SSD, so at this point I'd rather reformat it and flash Ubuntu on it again. Any suggestions on how I can do this

Comment: If you want to reformat then do it. If you want to reinstall Ubuntu then do it. What currently is in the drive, encrypted or not is irrelevant.

Comment: Next time keep the **recovery key, also known as recovery password** In a safe place.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I Reinstall and Format An Encrypted Hard-drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/364057/can-i-reinstall-and-format-an-encrypted-hard-drive)